# Changing the state of the input checkbox AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How to change the checkbok state depending on the value of the parameter?
Example: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ahoncharuk/h7c80wew/4/)

**HTML:**

```
<body  ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="rangeCtrl">
    Param:{{param}}
        <hr>
    <div>modelValue:{{modelValue}}</div>
      <input type="checkbox" style="width: 300px;"
             ng-change = "rangeChange()"
             ng-checked = "modelValue"
             ng-model = "modelValue">
    </div>
  </body>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('rangeCtrl', function($scope, $interval, $timeout) {

(function update() {
    $timeout(update, 1000);
    $scope.param = Math.round((Math.random()));
  }());    
    $scope.$watch('param',
        function(newVal, oldVal) {
            if (newVal == oldVal) {
                $scope.modelValue = oldVal;
            }
        });

    $interval(function() {
        $scope.$watch('param',
            function(newVal, oldVal) {
                if (newVal !== oldVal) {
                    $scope.modelValue = newVal;
                }
            });
    }, 25);   
    $scope.rangeChange = function() {         
    }
});
```

I assume that the problem lies in the fact that the parameter is not a boolean.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fiddle will work if you use

```
ng-checked = modelValue === 1
```

(assuming you want it to be checked when the value is 1)

Comment: OMG answer surprised
Thank you so much!